# Как оформить запрос в базу данных если нужно базироваться на дате?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Вот смотрите есть код -

```
 DateTime TodayDate = DateTime.Now.Date; // init    
var query = from o in this.dbContext.RentCarDBSet
                            where (DbFunctions.TruncateTime(o.StartDate) >= TodayDate)
                                orderby RentCarDB.StartDate
                            select o;
                this.rentCarDBViewSource.Source = query.ToList();
```

Где я проверяю дата из StartDate в таблице больше чем сегодняшняя. Это ок, но мне нужно поменять запрос так, что бы Проверялось не только Start Date а еще приплюсованная к этому Duration из той же таблицы.

> Т.е. o.StartDate + o.Duration (где первое это DateTime а второе String
>   (количество дней)) >= TodayDate

Как можно такое написать в запросе?

Comment: А что мешает так написать?

Comment: Как добавить к datetime string и потом сверить с datetime?

Comment: Сделать нормальное числовое поле в базе, не?

Comment: Мне необходимо сделать именно так. Не меня базуданных. Просто написать query правильное.

Comment: Так в чём проблема преобразовать строку в число, затем в timespan и сравнить?

Comment: Сейчас бы в базе хранить числа в `string`. Ну а че? Норм же

Comment: @duntik, по идее тип данных в базе не важен, важно как вы объявите это поле (свойство) у себя в объектной модели. А маппинг на это поле с преобразованием типа значения из БД возьмет на себя EF.